# If $|z-\frac 3z|=2$, Find the greatest value of $|z|$

Tags: complex-numbers

$$|z^2-3|=2|z|$$

And $$|z^2-3|\le |z|^2+3$$
$$2|z|\le |z|^2+3$$ which isn’t a valid equation, what’s going wrong?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Yes, the triangle inequality is an inequality, not an equality.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a traditional method, but you could use Lagrange multipliers and optimization

Comment: @lulu the greatest value possible of $z$

Comment: What about $2=|z-3/z|\geq |z|-|3/z|=|z|-3/|z|$?  So $$|z|^2-2|z|-3\le 0$$ making $|z|\le 3$.

Comment: Well, what have you tried?  Have you found some solutions, say?

Comment: @WETutorialSchool I was aware of that, but I wanted to know why mine doesn’t work.

Comment: Nothing went wrong in your attempt.  It just doesn't yield a result.  Your last inequality is still true.

Comment: If you let $z=a+ib$ and square both sides of $|z^2-3|=2|z|$, you end up with a fourth order equation in $a$ and $b$.  Then let $\alpha = a^2$ and $\beta=b^2$.  This reduces to a quadratic in $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (a conic section).

Comment: $(\alpha + \beta)^2 - 10 \alpha +2\beta +9=0$.

Comment: z=3 is feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing an equation with an inequation, which is a weaker condition. Doing that, you integrate alien solutions. (Though the inequation is "valid".)

Answer (score 1):

Hint

Use https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/ComplexNumberInequalities.shtml

$$|z|+\dfrac3{|-z|}\ge \left|z-\dfrac3z\right|\ge|z|-\dfrac3{|z|}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your inequality $2|z|\le|z|^2+3$ is very much valid.  For example, $|z|=2$ satisfies it.

The *maximum* value of $|z|$ that allows this inequality is the maximum root of the corresponding equality $2|z|=|z|^2+3$, which can be solved by the usual methods for quadratic equations to give $|z|=3$.

Thus $|z|=3$ is *an* upper bound.  To prove that it is the *sharp* upper bound, meaning the true maximum, simply try $z=3$ itself in your original equation $|z-(3/z)|=2$.

Comment: Very nice! ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Maximizing $a^2+b^2$ with the constraint $(a^2+b^2)^2-10a^2+2b^2+9 = 0$ (please see comments above) results in the two solutions $(3,0)$ and $(-3,0)$, thus the greatest value of $z$ is 3 and occurs at $z\in \{ -3,3\}$.

Here is a picture of the curve plotted in *Mathematica* along with the circle $|z|=3$.

[image]